# File Name Format Match (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, regex, xml, string

I am working on XML feeds and I have few XML files of two formats which are very similar:

XML 1 format

```
c<date><id><time>.xml
```

XML 2 format

```
c<date><id><time><revision>.xml
```

where:

- `C` is always 1 char
- `DATE` is always char format
- `ID` is at least 5 char but could increase time to time.
- `TIME` s always 4 char format
- `REVISION` is always 4 letter format

---

Now you can understand the issue is to separate the first format from the second format when the ID changes dynamically.

I am using `preg_match` alongside RegEx to match the whole format but my real question is there any way of actually matching the formats even if the ID changes dynamically into `7`, `8` or `9` chars?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what have you tried so far

Comment: format of date? `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: for `id` :- `\w{5,}`

Comment: Could you not put a `_` before the `<revision>` and then just test for that?

Comment: unluckily I can't change the files format, I have tried removing the last strings and first strings leaving the ID but it won't match the ones with revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format:

```
c :- [A-Za-z]  (if you want digits also, you can use [A-Za-z0-9])
Date :- \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}
id :- \w{5,}  #It will match 5 or greater than 5 characters in id
Time :- \d{4}
Revision :- \w{4}
```

Comment: yeah date format is ddmmyyyy but what is w{5,} doing?

I don't have an extensive knowledge of regex.

Comment: @Gabs `\w` denotes `[A-Za-z0-9_]` character set..It matches any character present in the set..`{min, max}` denotes how many times previous match can be repeated..If you write it as `{5,}`, it denotes minimum 5 times and maximum whatever possible..So it is matching the `character class(\w)` minimum 5 number of times